# How to put a component / template placeholder in index.html in Angular?

Tags: angular, dom, angular-components, angular-template

In order to show the app as early as possible the index.html contains this markup (simplified):

```html
<div class="body-wrapper">

    <header>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        <div class="user">
            <!-- here user information should be displayed -->
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <app-root>

        </app-root>
    </div>

    <footer>My Footer</footer>

</div>
```

After the app has initialized I wanna display user information in the header.

Originally I placed the user markup and logic inside the app.component.html and thought I could position the user area back to the header (outside of `app-root`), but this is not possible due to some more complex css layout rules.

Now I was thinking it would be better to put a component placeholder in the index.html (or a `data-user`-attribute) and let the app component render the user component there.

The difficulty is that in the index.html, of course, any Angular related stuff doesn't work and might even break the rendering until Angular is there, so I think it's not possible just to place a `<ng-template>` there ...

What's your approach on this?

Comment: If you are using the angular-cli, they've made the `app-shell` for this exact purpose

Answer (score 0):

Yes in **index.html** angular related stuff would not work. So the best approach is to write the html code directly under the div where user information is to be displayed. Again this would be best only if you already have the user information, you need not want to wait for any data to be fetched.

And if there is some api call for gathering the user information, then you should take the header as well in the `<app-root>`.
The second option would not make the major difference in t rendering the page.